# use WWW::Mechanize without FETCHING url data (raw)

Tags: html, perl, parsing, formatting, mechanize

I am spending too much time writing code that already happens easily with [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize).

I'm searching for specific `<td>` classes in HTML using `WWW::Mechanize`. When I find my specific entry and append it to a list, I want to also initiate another `WWW::Mechanize` object on *raw* HTML data (as in, "fetch" the page; the page being my raw HTML data).

I can't find any constructors for `WWW::Mechanize` to construct without `->get()` / etc.  I just want to feed my raw HTML data into a new object and go from there, but I just can't find how!

I think I clarified my question without the need of posting code, but will if requested.

Comment: I don't think you mean *"raw"* here. Do you want the module to process  an HTML file or string as if it came via HTTP?

Comment: Have you considered using `WWW::Mechanize::Cached`?

Comment: Mechanize uses http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.72/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm under the hood, why not just use that?  You can feed it a reference to a content string to initialize it.